# How can I prevent OpenMDAO components from allocating large dense arrays for derivatives?

Tags: sparse-matrix, derivative, openmdao

I have some OpenMDAO components that do math on 1D lists of x-coordinates and 1D lists of y-coordinates, outputting lists of distance and angle from each pair. Each computation depends on only a single x and y.

They are similar to

```
x = cos(t)
y = sin(t)
d2 = x**2 + y**2
```

where in the `setup` method I've configured

```
self.add_input("t", shape_by_conn=True)
self.add_output("x", copy_shape="t")
self.add_output("y", copy_shape="t")
self.add_output("d2", copy_shape="t")
```

and the `compute` method works as expected. Typically `t` is a 1D array from `np.linspace()`.

In `setup_partials` I have

```
size = self._get_var_meta("t", "size")
self.declare_partials("x", ["t"],
    rows=range(size), cols=range(size))
self.declare_partials("y", ["t"],
    rows=range(size), cols=range(size))
self.declare_partials("d2", ["t"],
    rows=range(size), cols=range(size))
```

.

and in `compute_partials` I pass a 1D numpy array to `J["x", "t"]` and so on. The test `check_partials` throws no error when I set `t` to be of length 10. I do see it printing 10x10 arrays in its output if I do not have `out_stream=None`.

Yet, if I set `t` to have size 100000, when I run
`prob.check_partials(out_stream=None)` it tries to allocate a large array: `Unable to allocate 74.5 GiB for an array with shape (100000, 100000) and data type float64`. I would have expected that only arrays of size ~100000 would be allocated, not 100000^2.

The same error occurs if I do not run `check_partials`, but instead attach an `ExecComp`:

```
self.add_subsystem("hypotsq", om.ExecComp("d_sq = x**2 + y**2",
    has_diag_partials=True,
    x={"shape_by_conn":True},
    y={"copy_shape": "x"},
    d_sq={"copy_shape": "y"}))
```

The [doc page for Spartial partial derivatives](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/sparse_partials.html#feature-sparse-partials) mentions a "sparse `AssembledJacobian`" and also a "sparse global jacobian". Might I need one of those? Is there something else I've left out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During normal run, it will only allocate sparse jacobians. However, during check_partials, OpenMDAO allocates a second dense array for the FD partials to be put into.

OpenMDAO does this because in general, getting the rows/cols right is tricky and its often helpful to see the full jacobian matrix. Its clearly causing problems for your code, and there is a few workarounds I can suggest:

1. when you run check_partials, set up your component with a much smaller size. You can use the full size at run time, but for checking this is excessive.
2. if checking with a large value of `t` is important to you then consider using the [directional derivative checking instead.](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.6.0/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/check_partials_settings.html?highlight=directional#directional-derivatives)

Comment: This answers my question. I suppose I should ask a new question about why (with check_partials off) attaching an ExecComp causes the same error with large t.